# Считывание структуры из файла

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с проблемой считывания структуры. При считывании в структуру из файла я получаю неверное значение размера самого файла, который указан в заголовке. Прежде всего, я проверил его без структур, то есть просто сдвинул указатель и считал 4 байта информации:

```
//пример
seekp(2);
imgf.read((char*)&buf, sizeof(int));
```

Что у меня выдало верный размер файла. Но гораздо удобнее это все реализовать через структуры, которые у меня не выходит сделать верно. В чем же моя ошибка?

Файл `img.h`:

```
#ifndef IMG_H
#define IMG_H

class img
{
    public:
        img(char *);
        ~img();

        // Заголовок файла
        typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER
        {
            unsigned short bfType;
            unsigned int bfSize;
            unsigned short bfReserved1;
            unsigned short bfReserved2;
            unsigned int bfOffBits;
        } BITMAPFILEHEADER;

        void read_bitmap_f(BITMAPFILEHEADER &);
};

#endif // IMG_H
```

Файл `img.cpp`:

```
#include "img.h"
#include <fstream>

std::fstream imgf;
img::img(char * name_of_img_)
{
    imgf.open(name_of_img_);
}

void img::read_bitmap_f(BITMAPFILEHEADER &buf)
{
    imgf.read((char*)&buf, sizeof(buf));
}

img::~img()
{
    imgf.close();
}
```

Файл `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "img.h"
int main()
{
    img * imgf = new img("lena512.bmp");
    img::BITMAPFILEHEADER buf;
    imgf->read_bitmap_f(buf);
    std::cout << buf.bfSize << std::endl; // Выдает 4, хотя на самом деле изображение весит около 243КБ.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Компилятор выравнивает поля структуры для оптимизации доступа к памяти. Поэтому bfSize у вас скорей всего будет не со второго байта, а с четвертого.

Comment: pragma pack скорее всего придется использовать, причина описана выше.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Хм, даже не задумывался. Попробую о pragma pack почитать.

Comment: Ещё у вас объект класса img создается в main, но не удаляется.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Так деструктор вызывается же при выходе из области видимости и тут нет необходимости вызывать его явно, разве нет?

Comment: О выравнивании очень хорошо расписано в статье «Рост размеров структур»: http://www.viva64.com/ru/l/0023/.

Comment: Если было бы img imgf("lena512.bmp"); то да, а так, это только указатель, по выходу из области видимости он не удалит то, на что указывает.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Да, вы правы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [чтение структуры из файла в си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542127/%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы настраивать упаковку структуры, которая, к тому же, различается от компилятора к компилятору, лучше последовательно считывать значения и заносить их в поля этой структуры. Так как мы имеем дело с C++, для единообразия можно (и желательно) перегрузить оператор `operator>>`:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, BITMAPFILEHEADER& value)
{
    in >> value.bfType;
    in >> value.bfSize;
    in >> value.bfReserved1;
    in >> value.bfReserved2;
    in >> value.bfOffBits;

    return in;
}
```

Тогда файл `img.cpp` примет следующий вид:

```
// ...

void img::read_bitmap_f(BITMAPFILEHEADER& buf)
{
    imgf >> buf;
}

// ...
```

---

**UPD:** В комментариях 
@VladimirGamalian правильно заметил, что автор вопроса открывал файл в *текстовом* режиме. Чтобы вышеприведённый код работал корректно, с файлом надо работать в *двоичном* режиме.

Comment: Странно, ответ начал давать иной, а именно на много порядков выше, но все же неверный.

Comment: Перегрузил так, что глупо, но работает верно. http://pastebin.com/AYXiYU5X

Comment: В ответе не учитывается, что std::istream будет извлекать значения из текстового представления. Т.е. работать такой вариант будет некорректно. В pastebin.com/AYXiYU5X уже рабочий вариант, но имейте в виду, что на машинах с Big Endian архитектурой корректно работать не будет.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, спасибо, добавил замечания в свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас неправильно выравнены поля структуры в памяти. Почитать об этом можно, например, в статье «[Расставим точки над структурами C/C++](https://habrahabr.ru/post/142662/)».

Исправить можно, к примеру, так:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER
{
    unsigned short bfType;
    unsigned int bfSize;
    unsigned short bfReserved1;
    unsigned short bfReserved2;
    unsigned int bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Для gcc вместо pragma pack роднее будет использование ____attribute____ ((____packed____)) (по два подчеркивания, здесь в комментарии не получается записать правильно)