# чтение структуры из файла в си

Tags: c, struct

Запуталась с чтением структуры из файла и размещением их в памяти. Как мне известно, то компилятор производит выравнивание данных для увеличения производительности. Я пишу программку для чтения(только чтения) файловой структуры fat16 (исключительно в ознакомительных целях). вот сама структура

```
struct struct_fat16
{
    char Instruction[3];
    char IdOs[8];
    uint16_t BytesPerSector;    
    uint8_t SectorPerCluster;   
    uint16_t ReservedSectors;   
    uint8_t NubmerOfFATs;       
    uint16_t RootEntries;       
    uint16_t TotalSectors;      
    uint8_t MediaDescriptor;    
    uint16_t SectorPerFat;      
    uint16_t SectorPerTrack;    
    uint16_t Heads;             
    uint32_t HiddenSectors;     
    uint32_t BigTotalSectors;   
    uint8_t PhysicalDiskNumber; 
    uint8_t CurrentHead;        
    uint8_t Signature;          
    uint32_t VolumeSerialNumber;
    char VolumeLabel[11];       
    char SystemID[8];           
    char CodeBootLoader[448];   
    char BootSiganture[2];      
};
```

размер её в памяти занимает 520 байт у меня(хотя без выравнивания по идее 512).
для чтения использую следующую конструкцию:

```
struct struct_fat16 table;
if (-1 == fread(&table, sizeof(struct_fat16), 1, f))
{
    ...
}
```

но в таком случае считывается ведь 520 байт, а не 512, да и размещается данные в памяти стуктуры тоже неправильно. Поэтому возникает следующий вопрос:
есть ли возможность считать из файла данные и записать их сразу в структуру, то есть не используя промежуточный буфер и копирование каждого члена:

```
char tmp[512];
fread(&tmp, 512, 1, f));
memcpy(&table.Instruction, tmp, 3);
...//так для каждого члена структуры
memcpy(&table.BootSignature, tmp, 3);
```

Как вычислить размер самой структуры без учета выравнивания?
Придется брать размер каждого её члена и суммировать? Или есть какие ты иные средства?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct struct_fat16
{
    char Instruction[3];
    char IdOs[8];
    uint16_t BytesPerSector;    
    uint8_t SectorPerCluster;   
    uint16_t ReservedSectors;   
    uint8_t NubmerOfFATs;       
    uint16_t RootEntries;       
    uint16_t TotalSectors;      
    uint8_t MediaDescriptor;    
    uint16_t SectorPerFat;      
    uint16_t SectorPerTrack;    
    uint16_t Heads;             
    uint32_t HiddenSectors;     
    uint32_t BigTotalSectors;   
    uint8_t PhysicalDiskNumber; 
    uint8_t CurrentHead;        
    uint8_t Signature;          
    uint32_t VolumeSerialNumber;
    char VolumeLabel[11];       
    char SystemID[8];           
    char CodeBootLoader[448];   
    char BootSiganture[2];      
};
#pragma pack(0)
```

И будет ровно 512.

Comment: а какой практический смысл отключать упаковку структуры? Ради несколькох байт терять выравнивание по слову?

Comment: @pavel,  практический смысл изложен в вопросе: точное отображение сишной структуры на внешние данные.

Comment: вы меня немного не так поняли. Я имел ввиду когда может в реальном (не учебном проекте) это понадобится, мне интересно стало.

Comment: @pavel, при работе с любыми внешними данными, которые имеют определённую структуру. Начиная с какого-нибудь банального заголовка BMP,  заканчивая бинарными протоколами и передачей данных между машинами с разной разрядностью.

Comment: @PinkTux А про предыдущий вопросы не подскажете:Как вычислить размер самой структуры без учета выравнивания? Придется брать размер каждого её члена и суммировать?

Comment: @PinkTux глупость наверное сейчас спрошу: а и с выравниванием оставить и читать из файла и записывать в выровненную структуру возможно?

Comment: @rubeno4ka, выравнивание смещает ожидаемую позицию данных, так что начиная с определённого поля из структуры будет извлекаться мусор.

Comment: **Как вычислить размер самой структуры** - А чем Вам не нравится sizeof(struct struct_fat16) ? Включите прагму упаковки - получите один размер, выключите - другой.

Comment: @Sergey а как это сделать  динамически в программе?

Comment: @rubeno4ka, сделать динамически *что именно*? Размер структуры определяется один раз, на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @PinkTux я поэтому и спрашиваю. Мне предлагают включить и выключить. Я поэтому и спрашиваю как сделать это в ходе выполнения программы. Хочу следующее: вычислить размер структуры без выравнивания и считать его с диска, но данные структуры пусть будут выровнены в памяти. Я вижу только одно решение - сумма sizeof() каждого члена. Вот и спрашиваю - альтернатива такому решению есть?

Comment: @rubeno4ka,  если упаковка вам нужна только для чтения, то и заморачиваться не стоит. Просто читайте все элементы отдельно, как в ответе Arhad.

Comment: @PinkTux я просто думала, возможно есть какие-то хитрые фичи, которые позволяют вычислять так по хитрому. Но видимо всё ручками. Заморочиться хотела для себя.

Comment: **а как это сделать динамически в программе?** - Что "это"? Переключение прагмы упаковки? Никак. Эта прагма для КОМПИЛЯТОРА. И действует она только во время компиляции.  Если хотите сравнить результаты работы с прагмой и без - соберите два варианта программы - с включённой прагмой и без неё и запустите оба.

Comment: @rubeno4ka, "*вычислять так по хитрому*" - по-моему, вы слишком мудрите и пытаетесь перехитрить себя, придумывая проблемы там, где их нет.

Comment: "Динамически в программе" надо сделать две структуры - одну с упаковкой, из которой будут читаться все эти значения, и вторую - без упаковки. Во второй половина полей будут отсутствовать - потому что всякие SectorPerTrack и PhysicalDiskNumber умерли лет 20 назад.

Comment: я полдня пытался понять почему в программке то сегфолт, то munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer...

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, стоит переносить структуру поле за полем вместо считывания цельного куска? Тогда и с выравниванием полей бороться не придётся, и процессор сам будет рад выровненным данным.

```
struct struct_fat16 table;

fread(&table.fat16, sizeof(table.fat16), 1, f);
fread(&table.IdOs, sizeof(table.IdOs), 1, f);
// ...
fread(&table.BootSiganture, sizeof(table.BootSiganture), 1, f);

if(ferror() == 0)
{
    // Работаем дальше
}
else
    // Обрабатываем ошибку чтения
```

Comment: "*и процессор сам будет рад выровненным данным*" - а как рад будет программист, работающий с этим геморроем ради копеечной экономии! Представьте, вместо одной операции чтения/записи ему придётся совершать пару десятков...

Comment: @PinkTux, программист работает один раз (при написании), а процессору потом всё это считывать и выполнять, выполнять и записывать, и так много-много раз... Так что экономия не совсем копеечная. Кстати, один хороший человек сказал, что лениться должна машина, а не программист.

Comment: "*программист работает один раз*" - как уже упоминали не раз, после этого не забудьте прятаться от тех, кому этот код поддерживать. А, ну да, ещё индусам хорошо, с построчной оплатой :) Больше преимуществ не вижу. По крайней мере до тех пор, пока вы не покажете на прогонах в профайлере, что в каждом конкретном случае выгода от выравнивания явно превышает накладные расходы на многочисленные вызовы, и выгода от этой экономии превышает расходы на поддержку кода. Впрочем, хозяин - барин, моё дело только предложить решение задачи.

Comment: @PinkTux, не спорю, моё решение не истина в последней инстанции, а всего лишь рекомендация. Насчёт профайлера согласен, надо проводить анализ каждого случая в отдельности, чтобы определить его выгодность.

Comment: @Arhad для меня тогда проще считать всё сразу в буффер и оттуда заполнять. Мне кажется это оптимальнее будет(хотя если учесть что чтение с диска идет блоками, то скорее всего вся инфа будет в кеше, хотя я не настолько сильна в низкоуровневом программировании, чтобы сказать точно).

Comment: Советик человека, который понаписал много подобного низкоуровневого кода. Никогда так не делать. **Ни-ког-да.**  Хочется супер-оптимизации - стройте свои велосипеды (на чистом ассемблере, конечно же, и без всяких операционок - это ж неоптимально!), хочется нормальной жизни - надо пользоваться штатными средствами языка