# Выравнивание структур вручную

Tags: c++, c++11, выравнивание

Допустим вам требуется вручную выровнять все поля структуры по 4 байта. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
#pragma pack(push,1) //Или что-то аналогичное

//...

struct S{
    uint8_t a;

    uint8_t pad1;   //Выравнивание
    uint16_t pad2;  //Выравнивание

    uint32_t b;
};
```

Теперь вопрос. Какие еще есть способы добиться того-же результата? Атрибуты компилятора, какие-нибудь новые возможности языка(С++11, 14, 17, 20), трюки с битовыми полями?

Comment: Это плохой способ для выравнивания полей: он будет работать только при встроенном выравнивании в 1 байт.

Comment: Вам выравнивание нужно для блочного чтения из файла напрямую в переменную? Если да, то это плохой способ, рекомендую вместо этого поточное чтение. Подробнее см. в [моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513849/208074) на вопрос «Считывание структуры из файла».

Comment: @Arhad, нет. Это нужно для того, чтобы выполнить требование заказчика. Оно спущено сверху, и где-то на другом конце света другая команда разработчиков рассчитывает что структуры будут иметь такой вид.

Comment: @mega, можно подробнее? Желательно с примером

Comment: @mega, char же всегда по 1 байту выравнивается - разве нет?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, я бы для надёжности вместо uint16 поставил два uint8, впрочем, никаких сведений, что это надёжнее, у меня нет.

Comment: `другая команда разработчиков рассчитывает что структуры будут иметь такой вид` — двоичная совместимость, понятно. Можно попробовать связку `#pragme pack 1` для всей структуры и `std::aligned_storage` для полей.

Comment: Про `alignas` [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616184/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-alignas)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, посмотрите примеры: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86. Если Вы используете vs, то тут есть [базовая опция](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment): https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCGFO.png от нее зависит, как будут выравниваться поля в Ваших структурах. На базовую опцию влияет прагма pack, Harry показал пример.

Comment: @mega, ааа понял. Поправил вопрос

Comment: Ключевой вопрос: "Зачем вам это?", если не знаете, то лучше не надо. Обычно таким занимаются, когда хотят очень низкоуровневую сериализация, чтоб потом memcpy на структуру сделать при десериализации. Еще вариант, можно сохранить структуру в файл для дальнейшего использования ее через Memory Mapping. Если такая структура покидает вышу оперативку (или приходит из вне) надо не забывать про BigEndian/LittleEndian. Всякие выравнивания на 1, 2 байта или не кратны правильным значениям для конкретной архитектуры - зло

Answer (score 3):

В стандарте С++ есть в разделе 3.11 `alignof` и в 7.6.2 - `alignas`, т.е. вроде бы можно указать что-то типа `struct alignas(8) S { ... };`, но (чисто мое мнение) описано оно не очень внятно, что лично я по привычке использую средства компилятора.

В Visual C++, например, это (помимо ключика `/Zp`) [`#pragma pack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2e70t5y1.aspx), обеспечивающая тонкую настройку выравнивания - вплоть до отдельных структур.

Вот такой код в VC++ 2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct alignas(16) S16
{
    char a;
    int  b;
    char c;
    int  d;
};

struct alignas(4) S4
{
    char a;
    int  b;
    char c;
    int  d;
};


#pragma pack(push,1)
struct S1
{
    char a;
    int  b;
    char c;
    int  d;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push,2)
struct S2
{
    char a;
    int  b;
    char c;
    int  d;
};
#pragma pack(pop)


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "sizeof(S16) = " << sizeof(S16) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(S4)  = " << sizeof(S4) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(S2)  = " << sizeof(S2) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(S1)  = " << sizeof(S1) << endl;
}
```

дает

```
sizeof(S16) = 16
sizeof(S4)  = 16
sizeof(S2)  = 12
sizeof(S1)  = 10
```

Comment: `sizeof(S16) = 16` - эм.. Лично я не понял. Как и 12 и 10...

Comment: alignas и #pragma pack - это разные вещи, надо прояснить: alignas (alignment requirement) - выравнивание для структур, которое используется при выделении массива структур, или при формировании стекового фрейма во время пердачи аргументов в функцию. Т.е. alignas в данном случае - не по делу, лучше удалите и подберите другие примеры.

Comment: Удваиваю что сказал @mega. `alignas` [никакого эффекта не дает](http://cpp.sh/5lsh)

Comment: [Every object type has the property called alignment requirement, which is an integer value (of type std::size_t, always a power of 2) representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which objects of this type can be allocated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment). `alignas` будет работать только если его указать для каждого члена структуры, но этим как раз занимается `#pragma pack`

Comment: Ну, я ж и говорю, что `alignas` вещь туманная, и показал это своим кодом. Очень может быть, что я просто не умею его готовить (с), но мне выравнивание менять приходилось крайне редно, и всегда - на единицу :) Я предпочитаю старый добрый и хорошо проверенный `#pragma pack`. О чем и написал :)

Comment: У Вас 2 первых примера не по делу. Вот верный пример с `alignas`: https://ideone.com/7pugjC

Comment: @mega Наверняка. Я не слишком хорошо понимаю смысл этого выравнивания, и в ответе этого и не скрывал. Но и ваш пример, откровенно говоря, не совсем ясен - гляньте https://ideone.com/Lz4qAm - я хочу добиться того же, что и с помощью `#pragma pack(1)` - но фокус не удается. Покажите, как верно это сделать, чтобы `sizeof(B)` стал равен 9.

Comment: Вроде все понятно: на ideone выходит 4 байта - базовое выравнивание структуры и 2 байта - выравнивание поля, т.е. `(4 + 2 + 2 + 2) + 2 = 12`. Уменьшить эти выравнивания через `alignas` нет возможности, увеличить - можно. Поставьте, к примеру alignas(8), получите ожидаемые 32 байта. т.е. разница лишь в том, что `#pragma pack` умеет уменьшать выравнивание.

Comment: @mega Спасибо за разъяснение. Тогда действительно толку от него мало. Обычно вопрос в том, как упаковать на байт для каких-то переносимостей или там API...

Comment: @Harry cмотря для кого что "обычно". Для меня явные выравнивания как раз обычнее: требования всяких PHY, DSP или DMA на железе, ровно как и кодеков на PC внутри всяких Intel Media SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов это использовать свойства [битовых полей](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field):

```
struct S{
    uint8_t a;

    uint32_t :0;  //Выравнивание до границы 32-битного поля

    uint32_t b;
};
```

Неименованное битовое поле нулевой длинны заставляет компилятор "сделать отступ" до границы поля заданного типа.

> The special unnamed bit field of size zero can be forced to break up
>   padding. It specifies that the next bit field begins at the beginning
>   of its allocation unit.

Я, правда, немного сомневаюсь в переносимости этого решения. Но, вроде, [работает](http://cpp.sh/8fd2v)